# Showing and hiding elements on an interactive map using jQuery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am making a simple interactive map using some jquery but I am not sure how do it properly.

I  have a list of flags on a map and when the user clicks a flag (ie.France) a featured-post thumbnail will appear in a div (France div) and if they click it again it will disappear. The problem for me is when the "France" div is showing and I click a new flag ie. Brazil I cannot replace the "France" div with the "Brazil" div.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.france-posts').hide();
    $('#france_flag').click(function() {
        $('.france-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('.brazil-posts').hide();
    $('#brazil_flag').click(function() {
        $('.laos-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('.ireland-posts').hide();
    $('#ireland_flag').click(function() {
        $('.laos-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="france">
    <ul id="flags">
        <li id="france_flag" onclick="" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="brazil">
    <ul id="flags">
        <li id="brazil_flag" onclick="" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="ireland">
    <ul id="flags">
        <li id="ireland_flag" onclick="" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="flag-posts">
    <div class="france-posts">
        <?php query_posts(array('category__in' => array(4), 'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($currentid, array(120, 100)); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="brazil-posts">
        <?php query_posts(array('category__in' => array(5), 'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($currentid, array(120, 100)); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>                
    </div>

    <div class="ireland-posts">
        <?php query_posts(array('category__in' => array(6), 'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($currentid, array(120, 100)); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if this is a little vague.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got it to work with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.laos-posts').hide();
$('#laos_flag').click(function() {
    $('.selected').fadeOut();
    $('.laos-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.laos-posts').addClass("selected");
});

$('.vietnam-posts').hide();
$('#vietnam_flag').click(function() {
    $('.selected').fadeOut();
    $('.vietnam-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.vietnam-posts').addClass("selected");
});

$('.indonesia-posts').hide();
$('#indonesia_flag').click(function() {
    $('.selected').fadeOut();
    $('.indonesia-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    $('.indonesia-posts').addClass("selected");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you would like to hide the other posts when you click on a new one. so you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.france-posts').hide();
    $('#france_flag').click(function() {
        $('[class$=posts]').hide();
        $('.france-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('.brazil-posts').hide();
    $('#brazil_flag').click(function() {
        $('[class$=posts]').hide();
        $('.laos-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('.ireland-posts').hide();
    $('#ireland_flag').click(function() {
        $('[class$=posts]').hide();
        $('.laos-posts').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

this line will hide all divs whose class ends with 'posts', which from what it looks like will work for you -> `$('[class$=posts]').hide();`

there are other, better ways to handle this, such as having a `posts` and `flags` class and using a data object to track which element is being clicked, which would help reduce your code, but the above is the quick solution.

if you would like the old flag to fade out, just change the `hide()` to `fadeOut()`

Comment: Hi Evan, big thanks for helping me! I got it to work with the following code.